# Google Analytics tracking and reports per each store view

Tags: multistore, store-view, google-analytics

I'd want to have different reports for each store view in a single Magento store, if I add a different GA tracking code in each store view (e.g. ITA, ENG, FRA) this could make sense? According your experience this method will work properly?
And where is the best place to add the GA tracking: Configuration->Google API or enter directly the scripts in Design->HTML Head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Follow this Step

```
Stores > Configuration (Select Store View) > Sales > Google API > Account Number
```

[image]